# Dataframe.ixmax on timezone-signed datetime data

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe

I extracted some datetime data from my django app:

```py
data = list(MyModel.object.values_list("date1", "date2"))
# >>>
[
  (
    None,
    datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 9, 15, 43, 59, 433515, tzinfo=<UTC>)
  ),
  (
    datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 9, 15, 44, 27, 328075, tzinfo=<UTC>),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 9, 15, 44, 27, 328075, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  )
]
```

I input this in a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date1", "date2"])
```

and I want to know for each row which date column is the highest so I use the [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) function on axis=1:

```py
result = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

My column types are datetimes so they argmax should work on them.

```
df.dtypes
# >>>
# date1        datetime64[ns, UTC]
# date2        datetime64[ns, UTC]
# dtype: object
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In fact argmax does not seem to work on timezone-signed datetimes.
If all the datetimes in your df are on the same timezone, you can remove the timezone and it will give the same result:

```py
for col in ["date1", "date2"]:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]).dt.tz_localize(None)

df.dtypes
# >>>
# date1        datetime64[ns]
# date2        datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object

df.idxmax(axis=1) # <= this now works
```